# Python 3 run loop forever problems

Tags: python

im currently trying to get a script running that will loop forever but for some reason if i run this on a raspberry pi in an IDE it will loop forever but as soon as i execute it through the terminal/command line on boot it crashes or exits after one scan

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('barcode.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()


def create_table():
    cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Barcode(Barcode TEXT)')

create_table()

while True:
    barcode = input("Scan barcode: ")
    print("Barcode scanned: " + barcode)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Barcode VALUES (?)", [barcode])
    conn.commit()
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Please include the exeption + traceback (most recent call) that you see after the crash

Comment: I just tried that and cannot get it working to catch it, just closes after it crashes (New to Python so not 100% on things yet)

Comment: On the command line, run it with `python path_to_my_script.py | tee output.txt`. output.txt should contain the output even if the program crashes

Comment: Run the command above and get a "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects

Comment: Looks like it's being run in Python 2 and not Python 3 on start-up. I don't know how you're running this but use `python3 my_script.py`. In the case of Python 2, `input` will evaluate the input and automatically convert it to a number (in this case a `long`), rather than retaining the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is made clear from the error message in your comments:

```
"TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'long' objects
```

The `long` type does not exist in Python 3. I'm not sure how you configured this to run on startup, but it's using the Python 2 interpreter. In the case of your specific script:

```
barcode = input("Scan barcode: ")
print("Barcode scanned: " + barcode)
```

Is the offending code. `input` in Python 2 will automatically call `eval()` on the input and in this case it is able to convert it to be numerical. If you actually wanted this to run in Python 2, you would need `raw_input` instead, but then that code will not run in Python 3 because `raw_input` was removed.

I think the solution will be along the lines of changing `python myscript.py` to `python3 myscript.py`. If you're using NOOBS then you should have both already.

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed this issue